# Check authorization from xml userwise

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xmldocument

I have xml as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<menus>
  <menu name="WeightManagement">
    <user name="eu01\bsoni"></user>
    <user name="eu01\bve"></user>
  </menu>
  <menu name="CategoryManagement">
    <user name="eu01\bsoni"></user>
  </menu>
</menus>
```

I have windows authentication and want o check if user "eu01\bve" has access to Weight Management or CategoryManagement menu.

How can I do with checking randomly from xml for menu and user?

Comment: can the user have access to both `WeightManagement` and `CategoryManagement`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do

```
var doc=XDocument.Load(yourXmlFile);
string access=doc.Descendants().Elements("user")
                 .Where(x=>x.Attribute("name").Value=="eu01\bve")
                                                       ---------
                 .First().Parent.Attribute("name").Value;
```

Comment: Thanks.. I did it using below line  XmlNode userNode = docMappingXml.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("menus/menu[@name='{0}']/user[@name='{1}']", Menu, UserName));

Answer (score 1):

To get the menus user can access:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(xmlfile);

var menus = xDoc.XPathSelectElements(@"//user[@name='eu01\bve']")
                .Select(e => e.Parent.Attribute("name").Value)
                .ToList();
```